# SQL Server Group by each Day?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a database with for example (ID,Datetime) now i want to have the Count of IDs in one specific Calendar Week, but explicit for all single Days in this calendar week.

So for example if there are 1000 entries this week, it should be separated by:

```
Monday 300
Tuesday 200
Wednesday 150
....
```

Is that possible?

My query at the moment is:

```
SELECT     COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM         Abfragen
WHERE     (DATEPART(week, ErstelltAm) = 21) AND (DATEPART(year, ErstelltAm) = 2014)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS [Count],
        DATENAME(DW, ErstelltAm) AS [Day]
FROM         Abfragen
WHERE     (DATEPART(week, ErstelltAm) = 21) AND (DATEPART(year, ErstelltAm) = 2014)
GROUP BY DATENAME(DW, ErstelltAm)
```